# ORDER BY DATE BASED ON A SUBSTRING

Tags: oracle

For this sample issue, I have a simple table SAMPLE1 that has a column `FILENAME`, with the `VARCHAR2` datatype, that has the names of three text files. The following string portion of the file name **'12152021_0305'** is the the timestamp of when the files were generated in the format 'MMDDYYYY_HHMI'. I need to run a simple query(i.e select statement) to get the listing of files and sort them in Ascending order meaning that I want to order it by the earliest generated file **HHMI**(i.e 0305, 0321, 0327).
The column:

| FILENAME |
| --- |
| 12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0305_001.DAT |
| 12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0327_001.DAT |
| 12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0321_001.DAT |

The query I am using:

```
SELECT FILENAME
FROM   SAMPLE1
WHERE  FILENAME LIKE '12345_SA123%'
ORDER BY TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRIM(SUBSTR(FILENAME,21,8)),'MMDDYYYY_HHMI'), 'MMDDYYYY_HHMI') ASC;
```

The issue is that I am getting the invalid number error "ORA-01481: invalid number format model". I have also used order by without the `TO_CHAR` function but it does not provide the file listing in ascending order. Please let me know if there better solution to this.

I also tried the following query but the results are not provided in ascending order:

```
SELECT FILENAME
FROM   SAMPLE1
WHERE  FILENAME LIKE '12345_SA123%'
ORDER BY TO_DATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(FILENAME,21,8)),'MMDDYYYY_HHMI') ASC;
```

It is providing them in order listed in the table column, not as following:

```
12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0305_001.DAT

12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0321_001.DAT

12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0327_001.DAT
```

Comment: `'MMDDYYYY_HHMI'` is a date format filter; why are you using it with to_char to convert a character to a character? Try `TO_DATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(FILENAME,21,8)),'MMDDYYYY_HHMI')`.

Comment: Hi @pmdba that is correct, the 'MMDDYYYY_HHMI' is a date format filter. I used TO_CHAR because other examples in the Oracle forum page were using when conducting a TO-DATE sort. I have tried the snipper solution you provided before. However, it is not sorting the list of files in the files in ascending order. It is providing the following sort.  12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0305_001.DAT
12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0327_001.DAT
12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0321_001.DAT

Comment: @pmdba I think it should provide it in the following: 12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0305_001.DAT 12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0321_001.DAT 12345_SA123_ALL_OUT_12152021_0327_001.DAT

Comment: `SUBSTR(FILENAME,21,8)` only contains the date part. Further, `TO_DATE()` would strip the time part anyway.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY TO_DATE(TRIM(SUBSTR(FILENAME,21,13)),'MMDDYYYY_HH24MI')` in order to get also the time.

Comment: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(...,'MMDDYYYY_HHMI'), 'MMDDYYYY_HHMI')` looks a bit useless to me. It is like `x + 1 - 1`

Comment: Thanks for the input @mustaccio..

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit , I noticed that after posting this question and works. Thanks for the input